Is there a name for and a use for a tagged union where all the constructors take the exact same type?
A tagged union or disjoint union is a data structure that can contain a value of different types, depending on its tag. What if all the tags correspond to using the same type, say A?
To clarify the question, I'm asking about types such as A + A + A + A where each option has the same type. This could alternatively be represented as something like the type 4×A with members { (0, a₀), (1, a₁), (2, a₂), (3, a₃) }.
Is there in general any point to this? I'm asking because it seems like this would be the categorical dual of an array type (if you were to represent arrays as monotypical products.) Is this meaningful or just a mostly useless mathematical artifact only relevant to specific applications?

Not sure I'm answering your question, but your insight can be seen as a case of the question of type isomorphisms. Two types are isomorphic when we can convert between them without loosing information. Whether two types are isomorphic or not, depends on the ambient programming language, including the chosen notion of equality, such as β vs η-equality. See e.g. Axioms and Decidability for Type Isomorphism in the Presence of Sums as a starting point.

Type isomorphisms are useful if you can use a them to code up 'missing' type constructors. For example System F doesn't seem to have algebraic data types, but they can be coded up.

If you think carefully, you realise that under the hood all code gets executed by a conventional processor which has just one data type: a gigantic bitvector, and other data types emerge (in complicated ways) by type isomorphisms. (At least if we squint a bit.)

It can be seen as a special case of a co-power. An $n$-fold power of $A$ is $A^n$. An $n$-fold copower is $n \times A$.

Thank you @MartinBerger. I will look at that.

@AndrejBauer This is interesting. Could you recommend anything as a basic introduction to co-powers? I'm not familiar. I see there's an nLab article but I haven't checked it yet.

The nLab will do, take the category of sets enriched over itself, and interpret $n$ as a set with $n$ elements.

I don't know a name for this, but it is extremely useful (see below). The point is that the tag carries information; the exact amount of information depends on how many tags there can be, as witnessed by the isomorphism you yourself exhibit.
The point is that information meaningful to the programmer, i.e. intensional information, can be encoded in the tags, which makes the resulting code much more meaningful and thus tends to be more maintainable. Code ought to be written as much for future programmers' understanding as for a computers' current consumption.
There this is particularly useful is when A is actually itself used to encode completely different information, so that to "make sense" of A, you need to know the tag. The most obvious is coordinate system (i.e. you can use 2 doubles to encode both cartesian and polar coordinates, but you sure need to know which one you have to interpret it properly!). int is almost worse, in that there's a plethora of (incompatible, incomparable) things that can be coded as an int but it would be non-sensible to do arithmetic on.
I realize that this is an odd answer on the cstheory SE! The 'interesting theoretical content' of the question has already been well answered by Martin Berger (and if you're interested in that part, I've written more than one paper on that theory). But I think the question you were asking seemed to lend itself best to how this can be useful in practice.

Indeed, thank you. I appreciate the concrete examples.
